# Assigning two non-overlapping numbers to each row of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I'm trying to create two new columns, `scorer_1` and `scorer_2`. The goal is to assign a value between 1 and 4 for each cell in these columns, with the following requirements:

- Within each row, `scorer_1` and `scorer_2` **cannot** be the same value
- Across all rows, both `scorer_1` and `scorer_2` columns should have equal numbers of 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s

I know one way to do this would be to make `scorer_1` a repeating array of 1:4, and then `scorer_2` could be that same array shifted 1-3 positions forward. But I'm hoping there's a more "random" way to implement this, since ideally I don't always want the values in `scorer_1` and `scorer_2` to be systematically related.

Seems like it shouldn't be that hard of a problem, but I can't figure it out.

Here's a very simple code snippit to generate the kind of dataframe I'm working with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

df <- data.frame(id = stri_rand_strings(16, 5),
                 scorer_1 = NA,
                 scorer_2 = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at it. The caveat is that the number of rows produced is slightly less than what you specify, so you might have to do this a few times and bind the columns to get exactly the number you need. Let me know if this works.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

set.seed(11)
num_rows = 1000

x <- sample.int(4, num_rows, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(scorer_1 = x,
           scorer_2 = rev(y)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(scorer_1 != scorer_2)

df$strings <- stri_rand_strings(nrow(df), 5)

table(df$scorer_1)
#   1   2   3   4 
# 188 182 191 183 

table(df$scorer_2)
#   1   2   3   4 
# 188 182 191 183
```